# Competition using Kentico API - editing comments in workflow

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I would like to add content to Kentico CMS Tree using Kentico 7 API in ASP.NET web forms. Main idea: users send the application to the competition via form on my site and I would like to save this application on CMS tree. It will be a competition with hierarhical tree structure of document types:

> > Competition -> Competition Application -> Application Comment

I would like content editor to clean unappropriate comments. 
I have three servers: development environment, staging and production. Content editors have permissions to edit data only on staging. But if I save user application to CMS tree they couldn't do it in staging environment (you can see in only on production). I will be using workflows so it is necessary to use Kentico API. I also cannot give permissions to content editors to edit data on the production environment directly.

So how can I make a competition using API, access workflows and allow content editors edit bad comments on staging? Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem? I would like to avoid making separate website with backoffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some time to read [Kentico's documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0rc/devguide/index.html?documents_api_examples_creating_documents.htm) on working with documents and the workflow using their API.

In particular, read how to [create documents](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0rc/devguide/index.html?documents_api_examples_creating_documents.htm) and how to control [workflow](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0rc/devguide/index.html?documents_api_examples_creating_documents.htm)

You can control whether or not a document is published by manipulating what step it's in in the workflow.

You can also manually synchronize documents using the staging module's API.  Its documentation can be found [here](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0rc/devguide/index.html?documents_api_examples_creating_documents.htm)

Comment: I don't have a problem with implementing this - I have already done it and it works, but I feel that my conception for the competition were wrong - we have problems with editing comments because of lack of opportunity to edit them on staging. On the other hand I don't want to make separate website for content editor to edit things on the cms tree. Any idea how to change the mechanics of my system to allow easier edit things?

Comment: I would just use a simple workflow where a document has to be approved before it's published. User submits comment, comment document is created as an unpublished doc, synch the unpublished doc to staging, your moderators review, if they approve it it becomes published and you synch it back to production. You'll have to create some custom controls and methods to make all this happen at the right time and in the right order, but it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about synch comment back to staging!